# WIe übersetzt man am besten "rebuffering"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

Google Translate gibt *Rebuffer* an, das ist meiner Meinung nach keine verständliche Übersetzung.

*Rebuffering* kann Teil einer Fehlermeldung sein, z.B. bie iTunes: *Rebuffering Stream*.

Beispielsatz:

> I keep getting a rebuffering message on Netflix! Help!

Diese Fehlermeldung könnte darauf hinweisen, dass es Probleme mit der Streamwiedergabe gibt, z.B. dass nicht genug Speicher vorhanden ist.

Comment: Erstmal schlägt dict.cc gar keine Übersetzung für "Rebuffering" vor. Es schlägt nur alternative Wörter für die Suche vor. Davon mal abgesehen, was ist eine rebuffering message? Muss man sich dafür mit Netflix auskennen? Ich weiß zwar, was ein Buffer ist, aber das hilft mir zum Verständnis nicht bei.

Comment: Ich danke vielmals für Ihre Anmerkungen.

Comment: Ich weiss nicht, warum da rebuffering statt nur buffering steht. Dementsprechend würde ich einfach sagen "puffere Daten" oder in einer Fehlermeldung "Fehler beim Puffern". Vielleicht würde ich auch eher "lade Daten" oder "warte auf Daten" verwenden, wenn ich das Fachwort "puffern" meinem Publikum nicht zumuten will.

Comment: "Pufferneuaufbau"

Comment: An sich ist der Begriff im Englischen schon nicht besonders treffend - Das müsste irgendwas mit "Recovering from buffer underflow" oder so heissen. Von daher gefällt mir "Pufferneuaufbau" ganz gut.

Comment: Es würde helfen, wenn Du beschriebest, was *rebuffering* überhaupt sein soll.

Comment: Pufferregenerierung/regeneration oder Pufferwiederholung?

Comment: Statt einem eher sperrigen zusammengesetzten Wort ("Pufferneuaufbau") würde ich eher etwas wie "Puffer wird (neu) aufgebaut/geladen" verwenden.

Comment: Zur Erklärung: Bei einem Stream werden die Daten parallel aus dem Netz geladen und abgespielt. Die Übertragungsgeschwindigkeit ist aber nicht konstant. Daher muss es einen Puffer geben, der heruntergeladene Daten aufnimmt, die dann in der Folge abgespielt werden. Außerdem wird häufig zu Beginn ein kurzes Stück gepuffert, um eine möglichst unterbrechungsfreie Wiedergabe zu ermöglichen. Ist die Übertragung aber zu lange langsamer als das Abspielen, läuft dieser Puffer gewissermaßen leer. Dann muss das Abspielen angehalten und der Puffer neu gefüllt werden.

Comment: Was die eigentliche Frage betrifft, ich würde auch eine Umschreibung mit einer Phrase vorschlagen, etwa "Auffrischung des Datenpuffers". Ich halte es auch für überlegenswert, von den technischen Details bzw. dem Wort "Puffer"/"Buffer" ganz wegzugehen, und etwas wie "Übertrage weitere Daten" oder "Lade weitere Daten herunter" zu formulieren. Das hängt dann vom konkreten Kontext und der Zielgruppe ab.

Comment: Wenn Du auf ein einzelnes Wort bestehst: Neupufferung oder auch Repufferung, denn Re~ ist ja eine häufige und daher bekannte Vorsilbe im Deutschen. Oder Pufferneuaufbau, ~regeneration. wie mfro und Beta vorschlugen.

Comment: Also, wenn das Problem nicht der Puffer ist, sondern dass die Daten noch nicht da sind, warum das dann nicht auch sagen? "Warte auf Daten" vielleicht? Oder gleich die eigentliche Ursache angeben: "Stream zu langsam". Aber da dürfte die Marketingabteilung etwas dagegen haben :-)

Comment: Ist das wirklich eine Frage, die hier ins Forum gehört?

Comment: Rebuffering sieht, da kleingeschrieben, wie ein Verb aus. Daher muss auch das deutsche Wort ein Verb sein und, solange nicht am Satzanfang stehend, klein geschrieben werden. Da es Ringpuffer durchaus gibt ist dies jetzt auch nicht übertrieben spitzfindig.

Answer (score 4):

Das deutsche Wort für *buffering* ist *puffern*, wie die Puffer am Zug.

Das Problem ist die Vorsilbe *re-*, die im Englischen (wie im Französischen) sehr produktiv ist, und grob *wieder* bedeutet. Und ab da lässt sich keine wirklich kurze, knackige direkte Übersetzung finden.

*Pufferneuaufbau, Pufferauffüllung, füllt Puffer, …* wären einige Möglichkeiten, das ins Deutsche zu übertragen. Wirklich zufrieden wäre ich aber mit allen nicht, und würde lieber den englischen Ausdruck nehmen – oder gleich ganz auf *puffern* zurückfallen.

Answer (score 3):

"Pufferspeicher wird neu geladen" wäre eine gute Möglichkeit dass zu übersetzen

Ein Buffer ist ein [Pufferspeicher](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Pufferspeicher)

Der Prozess des "buffering" bedeutet nur den Pufferspeicher zu befüllen bzw. zu laden, ich würde laden verwenden da ich es aus dem Gebrauch in meinem Umfeld häufiger höre, wenn es um PCs geht)

re-buffering wird als nicht einfach "geladen" oder "befüllt" sondern erneut bzw. neu geladen bzw. gefüllt

Comment: Statt Pufferspeicher würde ich das Wort Zwischenspeicher bevorzugen.

Answer (score -5):

Das deutsche Wort "Puffer" oder "puffern" ist mitnichten eine eine Übersetzung für "[to] buffer".

So, wie der englische Begriff üblicherweise (und, so legt es die Erklärung nahe, auch hier) gebraucht wird, handelt es sich um einen Fachbegriff aus der Informatik. In der Informatik werden "Puffer, wie die Puffer am Zug" selten eingesetzt und darüber hinaus handelt es sich dabei auch funktional um unterschiedliche Dinge. Ein "Puffer" soll einen Zusammenstoß abfedern helfen, ein "buffer" ist eine Ansammlung auf Vorrat geladener Daten, die zur Verarbeitung anstehen. Während also in einem Text über Chemie "Puffer" bzw. eine "Pufferlösung" durchaus eine korrekte Übersetzung für "buffer" ist, weil hier die Konnotation des Abfederns konzeptionell übetragen wird, ist das im Zusammenhang mit der EDV nicht der Fall.

Fachbegriffe zu übersetzen ist immer schwierig und oft genug auch nicht sinnvoll - kein Mensch käme auf die Idee, die "Luxation" zu einer "Umrichtung" oder die "Infektion" zu einer "Hineinmachung" zu verdeutschen. Es stellt sich also die Frage, warum man nicht auch auf Deutsch "rebuffering" sagen kann? "Lade Daten" kann man jedenfalls nicht sagen, weil ein "rebuffering" (also das Verwerfen und der anschließende Neuaufbau einer auf Vorrat gefüllten Queue - pardon: Warteschlange) eben was anderes ist. Darüber hinaus ist "Lade Daten" nur das Ersetzen eines englischen Fremdwords durch ein lateinisches, richtig also: "Lade Sachverhaltsdarstellungen".

Also: "buffering" bezeichnet den Vorgang, wo Daten, die zur Verarbeitung anstehen, "auf Vorrat" geladen werden, um sicherzustellen, daß die verarbeitende Einheit auch immer was zu verarbeiten hat. "rebuffering" bedeutet, daß ein solcher, bereits aufgebauter "buffer" verworfen und anschließend neu aufgebaut wird.

Wenn man das also unbedingt übersetzen muß (was ich persönlich für eine schlechte Idee halte), könnte man "baue Zwischenspeicher (oder Vorratsspeicher, Datenvorrat) neu auf" verwenden.

Comment: Warum kann man nicht "Lade Daten" sagen? Beim Rebuffering werden ja wohl Daten in den Buffer geladen. Außerdem hat ein Buffer auf eine gewisse Weise schon auch die Aufgabe der Abfederung, nämlich Schwankungen im Throughput abzufedern.

Comment: Ja, Daten werden schon in den Buffer geladen, aber "lade Daten" hat eine viel weniger spezifische Bedeutung als "rebuffering". Die richtige Übersetzung für "car" ist ja auch nicht "Fortbewegungsmittel", selbst wenn ein "Auto" da darunter fällt.

Comment: Der Begriff Puffer oder Pufferspeicher ist in deutschen Informatiktexten durchaus gebräuchlich. In der breiten Öffentlichkeit wird ist er derzeit weniger modern und wohl auch nicht so vielen geläufig. Trotzdem kann man nicht pauschal sagen, dass diese Begriffe keine geeignete Übersetzung sind - das kommt sehr auf die Zielgruppe an.

Comment: Neupuffern hätte mein Vater, der kein IT-Nerd war, durchaus verstanden, rebuffern dagegen nicht. Das wäre also ein Grund, im Deutschen üblichere Ausdrücke zu verwenden, woraus nicht folgt, dass man rebuffern nicht auch verwenden kann. Belegen durch willkürliche Beispiele wie "Infektion" fehlt es an zwingender Kraft, weil es ebenso Gegenbeispiele gibt, in denen Übersetzungen weithin genutzt werden. Die Bedeutung von Puffer ist identisch, bei Bargeld-, Zeit-, Energie- und Lok. "man läßt in der Regel beide Dynamos parallel arbeiten, wobei die Batterie als Puffer wirkt" (1922) s.a. Puffhose.

Comment: Du hast natürlich vollkommen recht mit dem Argument, daß "mein Vater hätte" ein zwingendes Argument ist, während mein Beispiel "Infektion" völlig willkürlich war. Ich nehme an, dein Vater hat auch einen Selbstbeweger, der mit einem Viertopf-Vierbumms-Zerknalltreibling angetrieben wird.